# convert milisecons to normal date

Tags: javascript

```
function openAPage() {
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var myWin = window.open("http://www.sabah.com.tr","_blank")
var endTime = new Date().getTime();
var timeTaken = endTime-startTime;
myWin.close()

document.write(startTime);
document.write(endTime);
document.write(timeTaken);    
}
```

hi i want to see the date here "document.write(startTime);".. how can i convert

Comment: it is customary to accept the answer that solved your issue. Also up-voting the answers that helped you is highly appreciated as it is the way StackOverflow works.

Answer (score 3):

```
document.write(  new Date(startTime) );
```

If you check the [documentation for the Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) one of the constructors is

```
new Date(milliseconds)
```

This way you recreate a Date from the milliseconds passed as argument.
It counts *milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC*.

But keep in mind that the `window.open` will not wait until the window has loaded before continuing execution of the code. So your `startTime` and `endTime` variables will be always pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

Create your startTime with both a time and date and all will be well.

Like this:

```
var startTime = new Date().getDate();
var myWin = window.open("http://www.sabah.com.tr","_blank")
var endTime = new Date().getDate();
var timeTaken = endTime-startTime;
```

You can still determine the time difference (elapsed time) between them, but will also have the date available to the end of your routine.

```
document.write(startTime);
document.write(endTime);
document.write(timeTaken);
```